# How to make maven wait till tomcat stops

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, wait, jacoco

I am looking for a way to wait till my tomcat is stopped properly.

What I do:

I am starting my tomcat with a jacoco agent  pointing to a jacoco.exec file. The coverage data is written to the exec file at the tomcat shutdown.

So I want to wait till the tomcat is properly shut down in my maven projects.

When I Start tomcat I use maven wait to listen till the server responds for a URL.

```
<profile>
    <id>start-tomcat</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-tomcat</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${tomcat.home}/bin/catalina.sh</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>jpda</argument>
                                <argument>start</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wait-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>tomcat-server</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wait</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <protocol>http</protocol>
                            <host>${mc.host}</host>
                            <port>${tomcat.port}</port>
                            <file>/application-url.jsf</file>
                            <maxcount>20</maxcount>
                            <timeout>10000</timeout>
                            <read>true</read>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

This works fine with the server start.

But for the stop I can only do

```
<profile>
    <id>stop-tomcat</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-tocat</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${tomcat.home}/bin/catalina.sh</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>stop</argument>
                                <argument>-force</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

Which issues the command and the shell exits after that while making the shutting down a background process.

But by the time the jacoco.exec has not finalized

Can someone please help.

Comment: I can go with workarounds like starting a separate processes to monitor the port is released and continue etc .. but wanted a maven way of doing this.

Comment: It seems like I have no option other than use a shell that lookups for the existence of the process.  `while [[ "" != $(ps -ef |grep jacoco |grep -v grep |grep -v bash | awk '{print $2}') ]]  do
 #echo "server is live"
 if [[ "" != $(ps -ef |grep jacoco |grep -v grep |grep -v bash | awk '{print $2}') ]] 
 then 
  echo "process still runs"
 else 
  echo "no process" 
 fi
 sleep 5  
done`